# vertical-align of element not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

What I'm trying to achieve is a set of elements (boxes) with a link inside. This link should be on the bottom right, but the vertical-align property is not working

[image: What it looks like]

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4JMav/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">TEST 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TEST 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li
{
    display: inline-table;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul li a
{
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I also tried several combinations of vertical-align and absolute positioning, also using wrappers around the `a`-element, with no effort yet.

**Question**

How can I position the link on the bottom right, while still expanding the `a`-element over the entire square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical-align works only with table-cell:

```
ul li a {
text-align: right;
vertical-align: bottom;
display: table-cell;
height: 100%;
padding: 10px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4JMav/8/

Answer (score 1):

I would place the text inside a span, and then position that span absolute inside the a. Yhis would make it easy to set it to the bottom right.

Your css would look something like this:

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
ul li a span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

and an example: http://jsfiddle.net/E2kfd/

Comment: I personally don't like to introduce extra mark-up just for alignment.

Comment: @AndyG Agreed, but the asker clearly stated he wanted his links to occupy the entire `li` (which makes sense), and that is not the case in your answer. I am not a big fan of the `display: table-...` css, so this is IMO the correct way to go then...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, using positioning:

```
ul li
{
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
ul li a
{
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Personally, though, I would probably give give the ul `display: inline-table` and use `table-cell` for the li's.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgsw/4JMav/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You need the following change:

```
ul li a
{
    ...
    display: table-cell;
    ...
}
```

(Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4JMav/6/)

Vertical-align works differently for table cells and anything else: for the first, it aligns the content, for the other, it aligns the text content of the element in the line box. If you place a block into a (inline-) table, the CSS renderer generates the [anonymous table cell](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) with default vertical aligning and places the block in it. But when you convert the inner element itself into the table cell, it applies the vertical align you set.