# transform-style: preserve3d not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, 3d

I am using `transform-style: preserve3d` in order to create a flip animation. However, this animation is only 3-dimensional in Chrome, not in Firefox or IE 10. In these two browsers it's flat.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQf9j/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>TEST</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul
{
    -webkit-perspective: 600;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-perspective: 600;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
ul li
{
    display: inline-table;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg);
    -moz-transition: all 500ms;
}
```

**Question**

How can I make the rotation 3d in Firefox and IE, not only in Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add px's

```
-webkit-perspective: 600px;
-moz-perspective: 600px;
-ms-perspective: 600px;
perspective: 600px;
```

Comment: It's also necessary to change the display type to a block type (`inline-block` results in the same positioning behaviour), it [won't work with table types in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=726601).

Comment: But when I use `inline-block`, the alignment of the containing text does not work. See my previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384875/vertical-align-of-element-not-working   - Is there a way to make both work?